# Logic to an if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following logic in my view to choose which avatar picture to show depending on whether a persons profile is present

```
 <% if @profile %>
   <%= image_tag(@profile.avatar_url(:thumb)) %>
 <% else %>
   <%= image_tag(default_image_url) %>
 <% end %>
```

Helper method

```
def default_image_url
  hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(current_user.email)
  "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}?s=100&d=mm"
end
```

This works fine when someone has not created a profile, but when they do and still want to use their Gravatar this logic fails as my if condition then needs to be if

```
<% if @profile.avatar? %>
   <%= image_tag(@profile.avatar_url(:thumb)) %>
 <% else %>
   <%= image_tag(default_image_url) %>
 <% end %>
```

At the moment when a profile is created with no image uploaded by the user, there is no image displayed at all.

How can I cover all scenarios?

### Edit

I'm in the process of trying

```
<% unless @profile || @profile.avatar %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`Object#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try):

```
<% if @profile.try(:avatar?) %>
  <%= image_tag(@profile.avatar_url(:thumb)) %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag(default_image_url) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you.. ill look into this method .. .try isnt something ive used before, all working great by the way

Answer (score 5):

A bit of refactoring starting from @ArieShaw's answer:

Helper

```
def profile_image_url
  @profile.try(:avatar?) ? @profile.avatar_url(:thumb) : default_image_url
end
```

View

```
<%= image_tag profile_image_url %>
```

Comment: thats very nice, ternary operator yes?

Comment: Yes, [ternary operators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if) ;)

Comment: ill have to accept @ArieShaw's answer as she did get there first, but i do like your answer +1